# This is going to be my first C++ book with no pior coding/programming language and I can't decide

Tags: c++

I kept reading about Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup 2nd edition and C++ primer 5th edition. I kept reading that they were both amazing for someone like me. However I also kept seeing post that put one in the light and the other down for a said reason, while I look at another post and its the exact opposite. So I need some help picking what book is the one I should get as I will be purchasing one since I don't like pdf's.

Comment: You can find many different good books in the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Most of them are also available in pdf form. I usually prefer pdf over hardcopies as there are many advantages of pdf. If you want to purchase hardcopy instead of pdf then i suggest you to first read the pdf and then decide for yourself whether you like it or not. And if you do like the explanation given in the pdf then you can purchase a hardcopy for that particular book.

Comment: Note C++ Primer 6th edition is due out in a few months.

Comment: Yeah if theres going to be a new book i suppose ill buy that once released and use one a pdf for now, i'll go check what i prefer atm.